# How to use exponential backoff with manual acknowledgment of Kafka messages

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a Springboot project that receives messages on a Kafka topic. The application itself is fairly simple.

1. Receive a message
2. Perform a REST request to another service.
3. Acknowledge the message upon success.

If for whatever reason, the REST request fails, an indefinite exponential backoff is implemented to keep trying the REST request (Messages have an expiration time, which when exceeded, will be discarded to prevent messages permanently retrying).

Scenario:
A message is received that fails the REST request and is in the retry loop (Offset 1).
Another message is received that succeeds (Offset 2). The second message acknowledges the message because of its success, which sets the partition offset to 2.

If the application crashes or is brought down in this scenario, when it comes back up the message (offset 1) is lost.

What can I do to ensure the acknowledgments are sequential? Replaying messages is not a concern because there is deduplication logic implemented backed by a database that tracks message state.

Answer (score 1):

> an indefinite exponential backoff is implemented to keep trying the REST request

> Another message is received that succeeds (Offset 2).

That won't happen if you implement the indefinite retry via an `ExponentialBackOff` configured in the listener container's `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler`.

You will always get offset 1 re-delivered until successful; you will not see offset 2 before that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i appreciate it. When you mention 'you will not see offset 2 before that', does that mean the entire application will be blocked on the message being retried? The goal is to keep retrying failed messages but not impede ones that will be successful if tried.

Comment: You will be able to receive messages from other partitions (if you have concurrency > 1) but you cannot receive messages from further down the current partition. You can do it if you process records asynchronously, but that will introduce the nightmare of managing offsets. Concurrency is best achieved with Kafka by adding partitions. That said, if your rest service is down, it is down for all.

Comment: If you have a multi-broker cluster, and you have multiple partitions across different instances, it is possible that even a single consumer (concurrency=1) might still make progress because the failing record will not always be the first one delivered.